# Django - error message: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR654.png)
I'm having trouble solving this portion of my code.
This is the model.py inside my app.
The "image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)" keeps giving me an error. I install Pillow library but didn't solve the problem

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):


return self.address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error could mean that you have mixed spaces and tabs in you indentation, or other whitespace issues.

Is the line below it (line 19) empty or does in have some whitespace?

Comment: The line 19 it's just an empty space

Comment: Empty space, as in empty newline, or one space? I think the easiest solution would be to remove line 18 and 19 and retype (Do not copy and paste) the content of line 18 again.